# Django Migration Modify Inherited Default

Tags: django

I have a model class in Django `Parent` with a subclass `Child`. Parent has a boolean field `foo` which defaults to `True` that Child inherited. I'd like to migrate my Child class so that

1. All new Child objects have a default of False for the foo field
2. All existing Child objects have the foo field set to False

How can I achieve this in Django?

Comment: What did you try and which issue(s) did you face? A model update and migration + an [admin action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) to update existing values should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best solutions.

1. You can override the foo field in your Child model:

**models.py**

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    ...
    foo = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Child(Parent):
    ...
    foo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

2. For existing child instances, you can write a small script to update them. I usually create a view function and trigger it by visiting the associated url (but there are many ways to do this). Something like:

**views.py**

```
def update_children_foo_field(request):

    for child in Child.models.objects.filter(foo=True):
        child.foo = False
        child.save()

    return JsonResponse({'message' : 'Complete'})
```